# Core Razor Pages - Id not posting on form wrapped in modal

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to submit a form inside a modal from an `<a>` tag. I can do it with a button but I'd like to have everything uniform instead of mixing `<a>` with `<button>` tags.

Front end:

```
@page
@model AllCustomerModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AllCustomer";
}

<h2>All Customers</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Customer">Create New Customer</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Address")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Country")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("City")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Phone")
            </th>
            <th>Edit | Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.customerList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-page="./EditCustomer" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerID">Edit</a> |
                    @*<a class="btn btn-primary myButton" asp-page="./AllCustomer" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerID">Delete</a>*@
                    @*  <a asp-page="./AllCustomer" OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete(this)" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerID">Delete</a>*@
                    <a class="btn btn-primary myButton" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.CustomerID" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a>

                    @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary myButton" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.CustomerID" data-target="#myModal">
            Delete
        </button>*@
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <form id="myForm" method="post">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Customer</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" class="hiddenid" />
                    Are you sure you want to delete this customer?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.myButton').on('click', function (e) {
        var passedID = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(passedID);
        $(".modal-body .hiddenid").val(passedID);
    });
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
public class AllCustomerModel : PageModel
{
    DatabaseContext _context;
    public AllCustomerModel(DatabaseContext dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext;
    }

    public List<Customer> customerList { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        customerList = _context.CustomerTB.ToList();
    }

    public void OnPost(int? id)
    {
        Customer customer = Customer;

        if (customer.CustomerID != null)
        {
            _context.Remove(_context.CustomerTB.Find(customer.CustomerID));
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        customerList = _context.CustomerTB.ToList();
    }
}
```

I can see the Id in the console once the "Yes" button has been clicked so it seems something is missing in transition? What do I need to add in order to have the Id post back? Neither the Id or the Customer Id is set on the post.

Final note, if I use the code below instead of the `<a>` tag then everything works as expected:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary myButton" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.CustomerID" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `Request.Form` collection to access string-based index .Since you have set value to input area when link is clicked :

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function (e) {
      var passedID = $(this).data('id');
      console.log(passedID);
      $(".modal-body .hiddenid").val(passedID);
}
```

You can set `name` attribute to hidden input :

```
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenid" name="ID"  />
```

then get value after submit form :

```
var ID= Request.Form["ID"];
```